# Eager loading Parse current user

Tags: ios, parse-platform

When getting the current user, I would like to eager load some of there user properties. I now when using a query it is possible to use an "include" to eager load some properties. Who would I do that with the current user? I can't seem find it in the docs.

A hack would be to read the id of the current user and then do a query on the user class - but perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: Simple data attributes on the user class, or relationships? Why would your suggestion be a hack?

Comment: I have an attribute which is a small array of PFObjects which I would like to eager load when using PFUser.currentUser(). Perhaps not a hack, but would be nice if I could do it when using currentUser(). But perhaps that is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have described is the correct way of doing it, get the id of the current user and do a get on that user, using `includeKey:` for anything you want included (such as your array).

```
PFQuery userQuery = [PFUser query];
[userQuery includeKey:@"nameOfArrayColumn"];
[userQuery getObjectInBackgroundWithId:[PFUser currentUser].objectId block:^(user, NSError *error) {
    // do something with the populated user object
}];
```